# Unknown action The action 'linkedin' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth

I'm trying to implement Open Authorization within my Rails app so that users can log in with their LinkedIn accounts. When I click on a link to go to the LinkedIn authorization page, and then confirm my LinkedIn credentials, I get an error within my app:

```
Unknown action

The action 'linkedin' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

I'm almost positive the issues lies within my routes file. Many tutorials call for the following line to be added:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

However, I already have this line here for custom Devise logins:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

I tried switching them but that didn't work (as I expected). Is there a way to combine the two statements?

Thanks!

Issue with omniauth_callbacks_controller:
`The action 'linkedin' could not be found for OmniauthCallbacksController`

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < ApplicationController
    class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController   
def linkedin
    auth = env["omniauth.auth"]
    @user = User.connect_to_linkedin(request.env["omniauth.auth"],current_user)
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.linkedin_uid"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations",  :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

This means that you are customizing Devise's `RegistrationsController` and `OmniauthCallbacksController`.

For example:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
...
end
```

And

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
...
end
```

Comment: I think this solved the problem...but now there's a new one. If you can help with this that would be great! I now get an Unknown Action error: `The action 'linkedin' could not be found for OmniauthCallbacksController`. I added the controller code in my question.

Comment: Glad to help.:) You need to add an action called `linkedin` in your `OmniauthCallbacksController`. Check out this awesome railscasts video http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised for help.